# Who in the DC Universe can stop Superman if he has a breakdown?

Tags: comics, dc, superman

Is there anything or anyone in the DC universe that can defeat Superman just in case he goes berserk on everybody?

Maybe Batman stores kryptonite in his Cave or something. I don't know if Batman actually has kyptonite, the example was just a theoretical example.

Who can stop Superman if needed, and how?

Comment: I took the liberty of clarifying your question, since there seemed to be some confusion as to what you were asking. If my edit is not what you want to know, you can either rollback, or tell me, and I'll try to fix it.

Comment: As long as the question's meaning isn't changed, it's fine.

Comment: In the movie Justice League:Doom it is shown that BATMAN has devised a method to neutralize all the original members of Justice League including SUPERMAN

Comment: This has been marked as answered, but Lex Luthor killed Superman. This is accepted as canon because it HAD TO be approved by DC. I know this because I worked on the game and was privy to some of the more complicated story issues. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=laEGjdgtZSQ

Comment: This is an urgent question in [Irredeemable](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Irredeemable), along with the question of what can cause a Superman-like hero to snap.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

**[Superman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Superman_%28Clark_Kent%29) is arguably one of the most powerful metahumans on DC Earth. Since the DCnU reboot, it has not been determined if there is anyone physically more powerful.**

[image]

But if I were to consider all of the canon versions of Superman as a reference, Superman could be defeated by several heroes using a variety of techniques. Superman is amazingly tough and fantastically durable but not completely unstoppable.

### **Magical Opposition**

- **[Zatanna](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatanna), [Zatara](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zatara)**, and **[Doctor Fate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Fate)**: All are powerful users of magic, a primary weakness of Superman. They would have to be very crafty and likely would work best if all three of them were coordinated in their efforts.

[image]

- [**The Spectre**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectre_%28comics%29): Considered the wrath of God in previous versions of the DC Universe, his power was nearly without limits. Even Superman's prodigious abilities would be second to a fully unleashed, magically powered Spectre.

[image]

### **Physical Opposition**

- **[Captain Marvel/Shazam](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/William_Batson_%28New_Earth%29)**: Easily capable of going toe to toe with Superman for at least a while, Captain Marvel's greatest advantage is the magical origins of his powers. Any magical manifestation of his power would give him a good chance of damaging Superman and gaining a possible advantage.

[image]

- **[Wonder Woman](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_%28Diana_Prince%29)**: The strongest woman warrior in the DCnU, her physical prowess was once nearly the equal of Superman and she was trained as a warrior to boot. Her skill with weapons has few equals in the Justice League and all of her weapons were forged by the Gods, making them magical and able to harm Superman. The image is from *Injustice: Year Four* #9, where Diana defeats Clark (because of some complicated stuff).

[image]

- **[The Grail](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Grail_(Prime_Earth))**: as a daughter of Darkseid and an Amazon, Grail was able to defeat all members of Justice League, including Superman and Wonder Woman.

[image]

- **[The Martian Manhunter](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/J%27onn_J%27onzz_%28New_Earth%29)**: while he is just shy of Superman's raw physical power, his mental might is unequaled in the Justice League and he would be capable of attacking Superman both physically and mentally at the same time.
- **[Icon](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Augustus_Freeman_%28Dakotaverse%29)**: an alien being whose physical powers equal or perhaps even exceed that of the Kryptonian. He has in the past proven to be capable of holding his own against Superman, which is no mean feat.

[image]

### **Technological Opposition**

- **[Orion](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Orion_%28New_Earth%29) and [Big Barda](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Big_Barda_%28New_Earth%29) of the New Gods** (whose fate is unknown in the DCnU): Both incredibly powerful beings, physically and technologically, they would definitely give Superman a run for his money. Both have weapons capable of emitting radion energy, a signature energy of their worlds, capable of harming or even killing Superman.
- **[The Green Lanterns of Earth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_Lantern)** (Kyle Rayner, Guy Gardner, Jon Stewart, and Hal Jordan) with their oanite rings powered by the Green energy of Oa, they are able to create functional radiation signatures similar to kryptonite with comparable effects. They can also temper the radiation to limit the effect as well, binding or incapacitating him. Given the currently transforming state of the Lantern powers, their capabilities may be even greater than they have been in the past.

[image]

- **[Batman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman):** A masterful fighter, one of the finest on Earth, has also kept a ring made of Kryptonite in case Superman ever went rogue. In previous continuities, it was Superman himself who suggested that Batman keep such a weapon, just in case. While exposed to Kryptonite, Superman would be far more vulnerable and with the proper application of force by Batman, he would be able to defeat Superman in a confrontation.

[image]

Comment: This guy is rarely mentioned, but The Flash. At his fastest, he moves and reacts to events faster than light. Superman doesn't. Combine this with flash's "Infinite Mass Punch", and I'd give him a fair shake of beating Supes without taking any damage at all.

Comment: But the flash punches would be an equivalent to a june bug crashing into you a multiple number of times.

Comment: @Blue Yep, known on TVTropes as [Death of a Thousand Cuts](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/DeathOfAThousandCuts)

Comment: How about The Phantom Stranger?

Comment: In the old days, it was hard to define the Phantom Stranger's power level as well as the fact he rarely intervened in anything outside of the realms of magic. So, depending on when you reference, his power level was either as powerful as the Spectre or just a magical hero who only dealt with magical problems outside the realm of mortal men. So he did not make the cut because, in my opinion, he would be less inclined to resolve this problem, leaving it to other metahumans to handle.

Comment: This is a great and comprehensive answer, however one glaring omission is Alan Scott.

Comment: He was intentionally omitted because his power levels at the time were fluctuating. In the New 52 he has been relegated (back) to Earth 2. His power at the peak of his ability was certainly as good as the other Green Lanterns and likely to be as effective since his power was magical in origin. So in the Pre-Crisis and Post-Crisis universes he certainly would have been a contender.

Comment: This is one of the better answers I've seen on this sight. I would add that, in the relatively recent DC animated movie "Superman/Shazam: The Return of Black Adam," Black Adam would have defeated Supes if Shazam/Captain Marvel hadn't helped Superman out. Admittedly, that's probably not canon, but the reason was that, again, Superman was vulnerable to magic.

Comment: Darn detailed answer, good show!  Many of these I didn't think of, though GL would be my first thought. He does have the most powerful weapon the the universe... Plus in Vol 3 issues 63 & 64 [Parallax View: The Resurrection of Hal Jordan] Hal takes down the entire JLA, Superman included.

Comment: I really appreciate the BatCodpiece in that last picture... it shows that Batman has his priorities straight. Superman may still laser off his jaw and make him look like a carnival freak, but Gotham's finest testicles will remain safe.

Comment: Not the Martian Manhunter. Watch him get easily beat down http://idol-head.blogspot.com/2011/01/martian-manhunter-and-supergirl-vs.html

Answer (score 16):

Yes, [Batman really does carry kryptonite in case Superman lost control](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/how-long-has-batman-been-carrying-kryptonite).  This is revealed a number of times.  The government is also noted as stockpiling kryptonite for a similar reason.

Answer (score 11):

As dlanod mentioned, yes Batman keeps kryptonite to counter Superman.

In addition to this, Superman is [vulnerable to magic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6457/is-superman-vulnerable-to-magic), so a sufficient amount would be able to stop/control him.

During the [Batman story line with Hush](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman_Hush) Poison Ivy was able to control Superman with her... feminine wiles... and her kryptonite-laced-poison kisses.

Beings possessing immense strength and stamina have been able to counter Superman as well; [Doomsday](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doomsday_%28comics%29), [Darkseid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darkseid) and [Captain Marvel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Marvel_%28DC_Comics%29) for example.

Comment: Superman was controlled by Poison Ivy's mind controlling kisses which I think she used Kryptonite laced lipstick just to get to him, but the point is magic, hypnosis and Kryptonite can stop him.

Answer (score 4):

[The Endless](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_%28comics%29) are the manifestations of all life and action in the DC Universe. [**Death**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_%28DC_Comics%29), *[by definition](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Death_%28New_Earth%29)* could do the job.

To quote Death, in Sandman #20: "Façade":

> I'm not blessed, or merciful. I'm just me. I've got a job to do, and I do it. Listen: even as we're talking, I'm there for old and young, innocent and guilty, those who die together and those who die alone. I'm in cars and boats and planes; in hospitals and forests and abattoirs. For some folks death is a release, and for others death is an abomination, a terrible thing. But in the end, **I'm there for all of them.**

As [Superman made an appearance in Sandman #71](http://www.comicvine.com/the-sandman-71-the-wake-chapter-2-in-which-a-wake-/4000-41359/), part two of "The Wake," they are definitely in the same universe.

The real issue here is **if** Superman going berserk would warrant any concern from Death or The Endless. *Probably not.*

Comment: `Probably not` - yep.

Answer (score 2):

The Flash(Barry Allen of Wally West) could beat him. With the power to go at the speed of light with infinite mass punch(power of a dwarf star) he could. And there is that little thing called the Speed Force to back Flash up. I remember an instance in the comics, after the death of Bart Allen, Flash didnt want to kill Inertia, the murderer. Instead, he took away his speed. But it wasn't the becoming mortal kind-he did it so that Inertia was so slow it would take him a thousand years to *blink.* Plus he could always take Batman's kryptonite or the League could transport him to a place with no yellow sun, his power source.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF.SE. This answer makes sense. However, maybe you could format it a little bit so it is easier to read?

Answer (score 1):

[Lucifer Morningstar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_%28DC_Comics%29) could kill superman in the blink of an eye given that his powers are best characterised as "[near-omnipotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_%28DC_Comics%29#Powers_and_abilities)"

[image]

Any of [The Endless](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Endless) would do the trick as well.

Comment: How about backing up that opinion with some reference(s) from cannon material.

Answer (score 1):

Superman has very poor defence against magic. In Justice League Dark #1 he was torn to shreds by magic teeth, something all other members of the Justice League had no difficulty with. As Superman also does not have a regenerative healing factor he is also prone to being poisoned, Cheetah made him sick by biting him in an early Justice League (NU52) arc and most recently he's been infected by the Doomsday virus, a biological poison. He doesn't have strong defence against mind control either, he had to be saved from Despero by Martian Manhunter, who himself is a high level telepath. Of course he's more than a match for most comic book characters.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of DC Characters that could defeat Superman:

Mongul- An alien tyrant who has immense super-strength, invulnerability, a vast intellect and also quite a bit of hubris.  In the 1985 Superman Annual #11 (by alan moore and dave gibbons),
Mongul through clever deception nearly eliminates Superman, Batman and Wonder Woman with an alien plant called the Black Lotus and his raw physical power.

Swamp Thing- The living embodiment of the earth's elemental power, Swamp Thing has several abilities such as transporting himself through the earth, assuming the mass of any vegetation around him (increasing his size or becoming sub-atomic at will), super strength, and could even move his bio-electric field around, becoming phantom like.  In DC Comics Presents #85 (1985) Superman and Swamp Thing have an encounter (also written by alan moore) in which Swamp Thing is able to negate a kryptonian virus that is killing superman from within.  It is stated Swamp Thing is able to enter Superman's structure at will, as in later clashes Swamp Thing is able to jump into Superman's eyes when he uses x-ray vision on him while in a bio-electric state.  That could be a huge factor to defeat Superman.

Comment: I think it's been clearly demonstrated that Mongul CAN'T stop Superman.  He captured and subdued Supes, and Superman beat him down on Mongul's home turf.  Mongul brought the fight to Earth, and a recently-mostly-dead Superman (and his allies) beat him down again.  Every time they've met, Mongul has ended up on his back, despite his cleverest plots.  A Superman unrestrained by morality would crush him out of hand.

Answer (score 0):

This was originally posted over a year and a half ago, but what the hell...

Superman never goes all out. This is the problem with deciding who could beat him. Even when fighting for his life, he restrains himself. Take off those self imposed limits and you have a being who can drop tens of thousands of 50 megaton punches per second, each one landing with the fiery intensity of a universe being born. And as a being who surpasses even Batman's vaunted intellect and the ability to take in and process information at the speed of light, combined with a body capable of moving, acting, and reacting at those same speeds, he can land each punch from a different angle of his own choosing unless his opponent can move at similar speeds.

Most can't.

This is why Batman's Kryptonite Ring is a security blanket and no more. Superman can reduce Batman to a light-year long smear of subatomic particles before the realization that this was a bad idea makes it from one neural cluster to the other in Batman's entirely human mind.

Similarly, most of the others mentioned just don't have the speed, even if they have the strength and durability. There is a reason Captain Marvel and Black Adam are go-to guys for fighting Superman and other Kryptonians. They both have the strength, durability, speed, and intellect to keep up. Black Adam fights dirtier than Captain Marvel, which is why Cap sometimes seems weaker, but they really are equally matched.

I'm unsure how well the Green Lanterns would do. If the ring can boost their speed enough to compete, they have a chance. I am certain, however, that the Green Lantern with the best chance wasn't mentioned: Alan Scott. His ring is magical, which we all know is a specific weakness for Superman.

Icon was originally meant to be his universe's version of Superman, just as Majestic was his universe's version. Both have an excellent chance of matching Superman, especially Majestic, who was raised and trained as a warrior.

Spectre could end Superman if allowed the power to do so. His power is basically whatever The Presence wants it to be. If The Presence felt Superman needed to be put down, the Spectre could do it.

Any of the Endless could presumably do it as well, but they're anthropomorphic concepts as much as anything else. If Death decides Superman dies, he dies. End of story.

One last suggestion is Sodam Yat, especially when empowered as Ion. He's a Daxamite, with all Superman's powers, plus a Green Lantern ring on top of it. Add in the Ion Entity and Sodam Yat is basically a cosmic entity that never gets written as such.

Answer (score -2):

i agree with pretty much all the posts here but i just wanna weigh in on the screwattack gokuvs superman fight, that was a showcase fight only so of course supes would win, in an actual fightr of how they would fight out of 10 fights 7 of them would be draws since neither would be willing to go so far as to put the earth at risk and they could easily counter each others recharge tactics and such the other 3 would be split under battle of attrition, in which they are even, supes may have much more raw stats and quick charge BUT his abilities are very expensive ESPECIALLY heatvision and his invulnerability, the stronger the hit the more power it takes to take and gets increasingly more expensive, and unlike supes goku ALWAYS fights at extreme speeds and simmilarly to vegeta (not applicable here) he is a fighting genius able to keep up with him (unless previously stated supes goes all out) plus he punches hard enough that taking his hits coupled with fighting him supes would quickly become vulnerable.

point is, its a battle of whoevers power drops lower faster and low enough to be unable to withstand an attack, (and both have "doomsday" attacks, supes inifinate mass fist and gokus ultimate kamehameha both of which have pretty much the same amoiunt of power (by the way screw attack is wrong about their analasis of how energy/ki works in dbz as well as the whole can only give out what you cna give, it is shown multiple times over and over that is not true)

as for the question itself, captain atom can manipulatre the suns radiation as well as emit red sun radiation so he can drop supes abilities enough to fight on par with him (or at the very least just under shazam and black adams capacity to fight him)

Comment: The bulk of this answer deals with a character not in the DCU, which is what the question is asking.  I'd recommend editing all the stuff about Goku out, as this is not a discussion forum.