# How does superman fight magic?

Tags: dc, magic, superman

[Superman is terribly weak against magic.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6457/3804)

Tony Stark has different armours for different foe, Spider-man has different gadgets and Batman is prepared for almost anything.

Surely supes has learnt from his weakness. What can he do against magic?

Comment: Run the hell away?

Comment: What writers wants...

Comment: he calls ShaZaam

Comment: @chcuk: [Who?](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IAmNotShazam) [Don't worry, not a TV Tropes link.](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BlatantLies)

Comment: Superman could always punch a magic user. Or via ridiculous extreme speed could out-maneuver his foe, and punch them... Even if the magic user was employing a magic barrier, he could simply throw a boat at them. Few people seem to be able to repel boats with their magic.

Comment: What's that Vlad Taltos quote?  "No matter how subtle the wizard, a knife between the shoulder blades will seriously cramp his style".  Although Supes wouldn't really _knife_ somebody...

Answer (score 6):

Against magic-using foes, Superman has limited options.

Typically, he will attempt to outthink his foes (such as Mytzlplk, who's powers may as well be magic).

If he can't outthink them, he relies on his allies (conveniently provided by team-up issues, or always present in group titles like JLA) who can combat magic effectively.

If the writers have stranded him, alone on foreign shores, against magical foes with none to aid him, he grits his teeth, poofs up his rockin' 90s mullet, and punches harder.

Comment: I miss my rockin' mullet.